# Gradient boosting practical example or broad hint needed

Tags: algorithm, tree

I recently got contact with boosting tree algorithms and implemented a small regression tree class for multidimensional outputs y1 .. yo depending ob features x1 .. xn.

Actually, I read several articles about boosting and the advantages of Friedmans stochastic gradient boosting, but I got stuck a bit implementing this, since all the math equations are quite hard for me - need it a bit more 'coding style'.

First of all: I did not find a practical example on that topic anywhere around. I know that there are third party libraries which could suite quite well, but I want to understand what's going on there and hence implement it by myself ;-)

Okay, assuming that my regression tree yields the required results which are needed for the boosting implementation, here is my problem now:

The algorithm builds up a regression forrest cosisting of n trees where the results of one tree are part of the inputs for the next tree. Since this is an iterative approach, it starts with an initial guess of the target funktion (prediction = intercept + x1*T1 + x2*T2 + ... + xnTn) where Tn is the prediction of the regression tree at position n and x is a weight for the prediction.

Pseudocode:

1. Initialize the intercept with the mean values of the o target dimensions (columns)
2. Initialize a matrix "h values" (current prediction result of the the ith iteration) with n rows, o columns
3. For iteration = 1 to n (number of trees)

3.1 create a gradient matrix (n rows, o cols) and initialize every row with the current training data subtracted by the current prediction of the result function

3.2 select a random subset of indexes between 0 and n of a given size (e.g. 50% of all data)

3.3 get the gradient rows as inputs for y and the corresponding x values and set up a new regression tree

3.4 train the tree and add it to the result function

3.5 Modify the "h values" row by row with the new row value += Prediciton * LearningRate

-- END OF ITERATIONS

4 return the result function

First of all, do you see an error in my understanding? If I take sample data, which performs quite well with a single tree (5% error with a depth of 10 and a minimum of three nodes per knot), I get an error of about 50 % - the graph is nearly a mean value line.

Second, I am not sure, whether I got the point with the "gradient", since I only use prediction - current value of the result function instead of a "real" loss function that I read everywhere about.

Third and last of all, I'm also not quite sure about point 2.5, is it all I have to do in here?

Any help or hint would be great.

Thanks a lot in advance

Monga